# How commonly do Anglophone judges abbreviate Claimant to C? Or Plaintiff to P or π?

Tags: legal-terms, judge

[Traditionally](https://www.quora.com/How-did-the-tradition-to-use-the-pi-symbol-for-plaintiff-and-delta-symbol-for-defendant-originate), [law students abbreviate Plaintiff to π.](https://redd.it/gfu0m7) Do trustable judges in the Anglosphere do this? After the [1999 Woolf reforms](https://chrisdaleoxford.com/2009/07/30/woolf-v-genn-the-), do British judges abbreviate Claimant to C?

British justices abbreviate Defendant to D. Lord Phillips did in para. 20, in [*The Catholic Child Welfare Society & Ors v Various Claimants & The Institute of the Brothers of the Christian Schools & Ors* [2012] UKSC 56](http://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKSC/2012/56.html).

> iv) It is possible for two different defendants, D2 and D3, each to be vicariously liable for the single tortious act of D1: *Viasystems (Tyneside) Ltd v Thermal Transfer (Northern) Ltd and others* [[2005] EWCA Civ 1151](https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWCA/Civ/2005/1151.html); [[2006] QB 510](https://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/redirect.cgi?path=/ew/cases/EWCA/Civ/2005/1151.html).

Lord Hughes and Lord Toulson did, in [*Hughes, R. v* [2013] UKSC 56](http://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKSC/2013/56.html).

> 30. [I omit sentences.] D1 is unable to swerve and is hit by the oncoming vehicle with the resulting death of the oncoming motorist and/or a passenger in one or both of the vehicles. D2 swerves but is struck by the oncoming car and the impact causes D2's vehicle to collide with another vehicle or a pedestrian. D3 swerves and avoids colliding with the oncoming vehicle but collides with another vehicle or pedestrian.

Lord Collins did, in [*Nilon Ltd & Anor v Royal Westminster Investments SA & Ors (British Virgin Islands)* [2015] UKPC 2](http://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKPC/2015/2.html).

> 1. These are appeals from a judgment of the Court of Appeal, Eastern Caribbean Supreme Court (Territory of the Virgin Islands). The primary questions which were the subject of argument were (1) whether a claimant (A) can bring proceedings for rectification of the share register of a company (D1) when the reason for rectification is an untried allegation that a defendant (D2) has agreed to allot shares in D1 to A; and (2) if so, whether D2 is a necessary and proper party to A’s claim against D1 and whether the BVI is an appropriate forum for A’s claim against D2.

Comment: E&W doesn't use "plaintiff" since the Woolf reforms of 1999, so I wouldn't expect to see it in judgements dated as above

Comment: "worldwide"? I would be very surprised if "Kläger" was abbreviated to "P" in Germany for example. Or to the mathematical symbol for PI, given that "P" is not pronounced "PI". You probably mean English speaking countries?

Comment: @alexg A link to the Woolf reforms which substituted "claimant" for "plaintiff." https://cms-lawnow.com/en/ealerts/1999/01/the-woolf-reforms-new-rules-in-the-courts-from-26-april-1999

Comment: @nvoigt The body text clarifies the title stating "Do trustable judges **in the Anglosphere** do this?" The brevity of a title often prevents it from being as precise at the body text.

Comment: @nvoigt Thanks. I added Anglophone now to the title.

Comment: @ohwilleke Thanks. Apology for mistake. I amended "worldwide" to Anglophone now.

Comment: @nvoigt English-speaking attorneys will widely recognize "π" as an abbreviation for "plaintiff, despite the pronounciation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

## Short Answer

> Traditionally, law students abbreviate Plaintiff to π. Do trustable
> judges in the Anglosphere do this?

No. Judges do not commonly use this abbreviation in the United States.

## Long Answer

I assume that the United States constitutes part of the "Anglosphere" (a term that could also arguably be limited to places where something close to a British dialect of English is spoken).

In the United States, the modern practices in judicial opinions and orders in American English legal writing is not to abbreviate the word "Plaintiff" or "Defendant" at all, in part, because modern word processing and modern writing styles make it unnecessary to do so. Abbreviations such as "P", "P1". "P2", "D", "D1" and "D2" are uncommon in American judicial writing.

There is also an unstated assumption in American English legal writing that one letter abbreviations are inherently prone to ambiguity and should be avoided. This is one of the reasons that even law students and practicing lawyers in their private handwritten notes, prefer the Greek letter symbol π to the abbreviation P when referring to a Plaintiff and the Greek letter symbol for delta (an empty triangle) to the abbreviation D when referring to a Defendant. The only one letter abbreviation commonly used by law students and lawyers in personal note taking (never in any kind of writing communicated to anyone else other than an outline for a law school course) is "K" for contract.

Sentences and paragraphs like the ones quotes in the question that refer to hypothetical fact patterns that describe parties by their civil procedural role, or summarize a current case posture in that manner, are also rather uncommon, although they are still used sometimes.

You rarely see sentences like the last two examples in the question at all in modern American English judicial writing. The first example in the question would likewise usually not be written the way that it is in modern American English judicial writing which would either omit the abbreviations entirely or would refer to the parties using terms other than "defendant" (e.g. "tortfeasor") that go to their role in the underlying transaction, rather than  their role in the current procedural posture of the case.

Ever since judicial orders began to be written mostly using word processors rather than by hand or with a manual typewriter, abbreviations have become rare in judicial writing made available to the public (who knows what judges write in their private notes) outside of quick "Minute Orders" entered almost as meeting minutes, usually following or during a hearing or trial and not meant for publication.

I did a quick non-scientific survey of minute orders I've seen recently in several cases where I've been a litigant for a party, in the state and federal courts of Colorado, in order to prepare this answer. In this skimmed review, I did not see the words "Plaintiff" or "Defendant" abbreviated once;  those words were spelled out when used. I did see the abbreviations "ATP" for "attorney(s) for Plaintiff or Petitioner" and "ATD" for "attorney(s) for the Defendant", and "ATR" for "attorney(s) for the Respondent or Receiver" all used fairly often in Minute Orders (although never in any other kind of judicial writing).

The preferred modern style in judicial writing modern formal than a Minute Order in the U.S. is to refer to parties who are natural persons, when possible, by surname (without honorifics like Mr. or Ms. or Dr.) unless there is a dispute between family members of the same surname in which case first names are used after introducing this abbreviation choice with an "I mean no disrespect, but want to avoid confusion" disclaimer from the judicial author. For entities, the preferred modern style is to refer to them with a shortened version of their entity name (e.g. "Skyline" for "Skyline Investment Group, LLC") if this does not lead to confusion. Groups of parties (such as a group of Plaintiffs) are usually referred to by the shortened name for just one of them, often the first named one, after an opening explanation that this is being done, or by their role in the underlying transactions (e.g. "investors" or "consumers" or "HOA members").

For example, a judge might write:

> Smith, the property owner, has sued Skyline, Jones and Nguyen
> (collectively "Skyline" in this opinion) for breaching a contract to
> build a residence on the property. Jones and Nguyen are vicariously
> liable, personally, for any breach of the construction contract with
> Smith because they personally guaranteed it.

This American English legal writing style is largely attributable to the advocacy in favor of a "plain English" and "modern" legal writing style of [Bryan A. Garner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryan_A._Garner), who is the editor of Black's Law dictionary and the leading living academic in the United States on the topic of legal writing.

Garner's stylistic preferences have been highly influential in modern American legal writing. And, Garner's view is that using civil procedural titles like "Plaintiff" or "Defendant" or "Petitioner" or "Respondent" is less effective rhetorically and more prone to confusion, than using party names or descriptors that aren't particular to the procedural posture of the case like "husband", "wife", "lender", "debtor", and "decedent" which instead go to their role in the underlying facts of the case. Of course, if you aren't routinely referring to parties as "Plaintiff" and "Defendant" then there is no good reason to abbreviate those terms.

Comment: maybe they mean places that call the last letter of the alphabet zed?

Comment: An places that make cans out of aluminium.